# Excel how do I enable import data from web?

Tags: excel, web

As Excel beginner, I recently figure out that there's a functionality to load web data into excel.

Many tutorials suggest to find this functionality under Data, Import... etc... 
But the only option I find are : From FileMaker, FRom HTML . From text, 
new database Query. No from web option...

How do I activate the functionality?
Using Excel for Mac, version 15.21

Comment: Isn't that "from HTML"? The language that all web pages are written in?

Comment: That option looks like giving you the chance to load data from a local HTMl file.... maybe I should setup some remote connection? I would expect to specify a url not a local file....

Comment: You can save a web page to your local file system. All web browsers allow this. Then you can open it with Excel. This won't allow you to import data from the web in realtime, though.

Comment: Isn't this helpful? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSR8DA01jQ

Comment: That's not what I need. Web data is dynamic, I'm not going to save the HTML page anytime I need to reaload the data... I'm sure there's a smarter solution

Comment: I think the youtube video is on a different version of Excel.  I have "From HTML" instead "From Web" button. When I click it it pops up the same window when I want to open a new file. I dont have "new web query" dialog like in the video...

Comment: If you want to load dynamic data into Excel (which doesn't sound like something Excel was built for), I would look at some custom programming. Perhaps even excluding Excel altogether.